# i can't create model in vs2017 from mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity

I'm following this tutorial

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html

for create model from Mysql
but after step 5 when i click Next the Entity Data Model Wizard windows closed and not add any model in my project!

what i do to fixed this problem?

Comment: check connection string

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48539581/i-cant-add-model-from-mysql-in-vs2017

Comment: Have you just asked the same question again? Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: No references to external sources please. Post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is a known bug in Connector/NET: [Bug 89338](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89338). You'll have to wait for Oracle to fix this bug in their connector library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [i can't add model from mysql in VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48539581/i-cant-add-model-from-mysql-in-vs2017)